# What is the best way to convert text from different direction?

Tags: html, localization

I'm creating an interface that has a list of employees with the names of each one. But in this list I'm going to have random names from all countries. And in the interface there will be two text directions `LTR` (*Left To Right*) and `RTL` (*Right To Left*).

However, I don't know the names that go into this list of employees as I'm going to take it from the database and insert it into my document and my solution was to insert the names inside each `<bdi>` element:

```
<li><bdi>Bernado Silva</bdi></li>
<li><bdi>Lucas Oliveira</bdi></li>
<li><bdi>إبرو</bdi></li>
```

Thus, if the name is in a right-to-left direction, the browser will treat the text in isolation from the surrounding text. But I wonder, is this right? I care about accessibility and semantics and if the name is `LTR`, wouldn't it be incorrect to say it's `RTL`?